# Regex para split de operadores de comparação

Tags: java, regex

Estou com dificuldades para montar uma expressão regular que atenda a seguinte condição:

```
String formula = " 100 != (50 + 20 + 30) ";

String arr = formula.split(" somente os caracteres: '=', '!=', '<', '<=','>=' e '>' ");
```

Como ficaria essa expressão? Também gostaria de não perder o operador no `split`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma alternativa é:

```
String formula = " 100 != (50 + 20 + 30) ";
String[] partes = formula.split("!?=|[<>]=?");
for (String s : partes) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

A regex usa [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (o caractere `|`, que significa **ou**), e tem duas opções:

- o caractere `!`, mas como tem um `?` logo depois, isso o torna [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html). Em seguida, temos sinal de igual (`=`). Assim, o trecho `!?=` pega tanto `!=` quanto `=`
- `[<>]=?`: uma [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) (`[<>]`, que corresponde a qualquer um dos 2 caracteres `<` ou `>`), seguida de sinal de igual opcional (`=?`). Assim, podemos ter `>`, `>=`, `<` ou `<=`

A saída é:

```
 100 
 (50 + 20 + 30)
```

---

Um detalhe é que esta regex também pode considerar casos como `10 ==== 1 + 9`, e o array resultante do `split` poderá ter vários elementos que são apenas uma string em branco.

Para evitar isso, podemos assumir que antes e depois do separador sempre tem um espaço:

```
String[] partes = formula.split(" (!?=|[<>]=?) ");
```

Repare que agora tem um espaço antes e outro depois da regex. E também agrupei tudo dentro de parênteses, pois os espaços devem estar antes e depois de ambas as possibilidades (sem os parênteses, a regex é interpretada como "tem espaço antes de `!?=` (mas depois tanto faz), **ou** tem espaço depois de `[<>]=?` (mas antes tanto faz)".

Mas este caso só funciona se tiver um espaço antes e depois do separador. Se este for o seu caso, pode usar esta mesmo.

---

Mas se quiser aceitar fórmulas sem espaços (como `10!=20`), pode verificar se antes e depois do separador só tem caracteres que não são os próprios separadores:

```
String[] partes = formula.split("(?<=[^!=<>])(!?=|[<>]=?)(?=[^!=<>])");
```

Agora eu uso [*lookarounds*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): o *lookbehind* (o trecho com `(?<=`) e o *lookahead* (o trecho com `(?=`), que servem para verificar se algo existe antes e depois. No caso, estou verificando `[^!=<>]` (qualquer coisa que **não** seja os caracteres `!`, `=`, `<` ou `>`) - o `^` logo depois do colchete de abertura faz com que a classe de caracteres seja [negada](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

O truque do *lookbehind* e *lookahead* é que eles só verificam se algo existe antes ou depois, mas este trecho não faz parte do *match*, e portanto não é removido no `split`.

Assim, a expressão ignora casos como `2===1+1`, além de fazer o `split` corretamente mesmo se não tiver espaços antes e depois do separador.

---

Após o `split`, o operador é perdido. Para recuperá-lo, você tem duas opções:

1. obtê-lo separadamente, usando a mesma regex:

```
String formula = " 100>=(50 + 20 + 30) ";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=[^!=<>])(!?=|[<>]=?)(?=[^!=<>])").matcher(formula);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); // >=
}
```

Eu uso `while` para o caso de ter mais de uma ocorrência do operador na string. Mas se quiser somente a primeira ocorrência, pode trocar para `if`.

2. obtê-lo no mesmo array retornado pelo `split`. Isso exige uma complicação a mais, pois é necessário outro *lookahead* e outro *lookbehind* em volta de toda a expressão:

```
String regexTemplate = "((?<=%1$s)|(?=%1$s))";
String formula = " 100>=(50 + 20 + 30) ";
String[] partes = formula.split(String.format(regexTemplate, "(?<=[^!=<>])(!?=|[<>]=?)(?=[^!=<>])"));
for (String s : partes) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

A ideia desta regex foi tirada [desta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2206432).
Basicamente, você usa `((?<= expressão )|(?= expressão))`. Ou seja, verifica as posições da string que contém a regex antes ou depois, e faz o `split` nessas posições. Como o *lookahead* e *lookbehind* não fazem parte do *match*, o operador também é retornado no `split`.

A saída é:

```
 100
>=
(50 + 20 + 30)
```

---

Se quiser incluir o operador `==`, mude a regex para:

```
String formula = " 100 == (50 + 20 + 30) ";
String[] partes = formula.split("[!=]?=|[<>]=?");
for (String s : partes) {
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Agora, em vez de apenas `!`, eu uso `[!=]`, que aceita tanto `!` quanto `=` antes do outro `=` (ou seja, aceita tanto `!=` quanto `==`).

Se quiser mudar as opções 1 e 2 acima, ficaria:

```
String formula = " 100==(50 + 20 + 30) ";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=[^!=<>])([!=]?=|[<>]=?)(?=[^!=<>])").matcher(formula);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); // ==
}
```

```
String regexTemplate = "((?<=%1$s)|(?=%1$s))";
String formula = " 100==(50 + 20 + 30) ";
String[] partes = formula.split(String.format(regexTemplate, "(?<=[^!=<>])([!=]?=|[<>]=?)(?=[^!=<>])"));
for (String s : partes) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Após realizar o split o operador " != " é perdido, consigo resgata-lo ?

Comment: @BrennoSegolim Sim, consegue. Atualizei a resposta

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda !

Comment: deparei-me com um erro na minha instrução, seguindo a lógica do regex acima não é possível obter-se o retorno caso a expressão contenha "==", correto?

Comment: @BrennoSegolim Atualizei a resposta

Comment: @hkotsubo é possivel seguir essa mesma lógica para uma expressão utilizando javascript?

Comment: @VictorHenrique Sim: https://jsfiddle.net/3ugj9txk/  (mas se sua dúvida for outra, sugiro que faça outra pergunta, pois aí ela fica visível pra todos na página principal e vc tem mais chances de alguém responder - se comentar aqui, provavelmente só eu vou ver, e ultimamente estou sem muito tempo para dedicar ao site...)